# Updating NumberLong through mongoose turns into TimeStamp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `bar` collection and each document has two fields corresponding to the following `barSchema` description on mongoose:

```
const barSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    "_id": SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    "index": SchemaTypes.Long,
  },
  { collection : 'bar' }
);
```

I have a unique document on `bar` collection, which I inserted with the following command:

```
db.bar.insert( { _id: ObjectId('565a07b5c1c80e6ee05cc326'),  index: NumberLong(1)} )
```

I can successfully update that document on mongo shell doing:

```
db.bar.update( { _id: ObjectId("565a07b5c1c80e6ee05cc326")} , {$set:{index: NumberLong(7)}})
```

Yet, if I do the same operation through mongoose that document will not be updated in the same manner. I made it in node.js with mongoose with the following statements for the previous `barSchema`:

```
const BarModel = mongoose.model('bar', barSchema);
BarModel.update(
  { _id: '565a07b5c1c80e6ee05cc326'},
  {$set: {index: '7'}},
  (err, tank) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(tank);
  }
)
```

After this update the resulting document is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("565a07b5c1c80e6ee05cc326"), "index" : Timestamp(0, 0) }
```

I already tried also to update with a long value from `mongoose.Types.Long.fromString("7")`, but nothing works fine and the result is always the above.

Comment: Are you using the [mongoose-long](https://github.com/aheckmann/mongoose-long) library for the `Long` type?

Comment: I am using mongoose-long for NumberLong mongodb type